# how do I join in an Repo.find_by() in elixir

Tags: elixir, ecto

I need to look up a user, but also join it with another table (partner). Here's the working code without the join:

```
result = Repo.get_by(User, login: auth.info.email)
```

The user table has a foreign key with the partner table, so I thought to try this:

```
result = Repo.get_by(User, %{ login: auth.info.email, join: :partner } )
```

But this results in:

```
field `User.join` in `where` does not exist in the schema in query:
```

so it's obviously taking the join as a column name.
I don't want to preload, because - as I understand - this will load the entire table in memory, and it can get big, so I need a join at the database level.

Comment: `preload` will only load the records associated with the selected user, not the whole table.

Comment: Can you give an example how to use in this case? I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't want to preload, because - as I understand - this will load the entire table in memory, and it can get big, so I need a join at the database level.

Preloading does not load the whole table in memory, but only the records where the specific foreign key matches the given struct's id.

Assuming `:partner` is either a `belongs_to` or `has_many` or `has_one` relationship of `User`, you can load it like this:

```
user = Repo.get_by!(User, login: auth.info.email) |> Repo.preload(:partner)
```

If you're relying on `Repo.get_by` to return a `nil` on no record found, you'll need to handle that case yourself since `Repo.preload` will raise an error if you pass it `nil` as the first argument:

```
user = if u = Repo.get_by(User, login: auth.info.email), do: Repo.preload(u, :partner), else: nil
```

After either of these, you can access `partner` as `user.partner`.

Comment: Is this the way joins should be handled, or is there a better way?